# npm version is different for sudo user and for regular user with sudo

Tags: linux, npm

can someone explain why I get the 4.2.0, please? (image)
I'm trying to have the same version for both superuser and 'regular' user.
when running:

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

nothing changes.

[image]

Comment: [whereis](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whereis) is your friend ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 can you please explain?

Comment: 1) Click on the link and read the man page for "whereis". 2) Type "whereis npm" as root.  3) Type "whereis npm" as normal user.  3) Compare and contrast ;)